# In multiple module gralde project, should I use one global gradle file or each module has their own respectively?

Tags: gradle

Suppose I have a gradle project named `Xenon`, and several modules there like `Xenon-Task`, `Xenon-API`, something like that.

Which style should be preferred. One means only one global project level gradle file VS every single module has their own gradle file respectively, project level only has module info, but no details which works inside module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: it depends. There is no "preferred" style, you're the one who choose.

General advice is to put all common logic in the higher level build files, in `allprojects` / `subprojects` blocks. Good candidates are `repositories` as they are the same for all the submodules or publishing configs.

However, there are plugins, like [The Application Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) that will have different configs in different modules (main classes). A set of particular submodule's dependencies will be different for each submodule as well. So put that in module's `build.gradle`.

Comment: OK, let's put common things in higher level gradle file, in practice, there always something not in common, so we put those things inside module respectively, so, at least there should be more than one gradle file, so, only one global gradle file is not a good choice, right?